# Are there any example of Mutual recursion?

Tags: recursion

Are there any examples for a recursive function that calls an other function which calls the first one too ?

Example :

```
function1()
{    
    //do something 
    function2();
    //do something
}

function2()
{
    //do something 
    function1();
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You just provided one :) unless you meant real life example?

Comment: The general term is “mutual recursion”, and yeah, there are many, many cases where the calls made by a function would be likely to cause a nested call into that function.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Mutual recursion is common in code that parses mathematical expressions (and other grammars). A recursive descent parser based on the grammar below will naturally contain mutual recursion: `expression-terms-term-factor-primary-expression`.

```
expression
    + terms
    - terms
    terms

terms
    term + terms
    term - terms

term
    factor
    factor * term
    factor / term

factor
    primary
    primary ^ factor

primary
    ( expression )
    number
    name
    name ( expression )
```

Comment: +1, I was thinking about this, too. In fact, using mutual tail recursion to implement automata is just a special case of a tail recursive descent parser, which in turn is a variant of a recursive descent parser.

Answer (score 19):

The proper term for this is Mutual Recursion.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion

There's an example on that page, I'll reproduce here in Java:

```
boolean even( int number )
{    
    if( number == 0 )
        return true;
    else
        return odd(abs(number)-1)
}

boolean odd( int number )
{
    if( number == 0 )
        return false;
    else
        return even(abs(number)-1);
}
```

Where abs( n ) means return the absolute value of a number.

Clearly this is not efficient, just to demonstrate a point.

Answer (score 13):

An example might be the minmax algorithm commonly used in game programs such as chess. Starting at the top of the game tree, the goal is to find the **maximum** value of all the nodes at the level below, whose values are defined as the **minimum** of the values of the nodes below that, whose values are defines as the **maximum** of the values below that, whose values ...

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two common sources of mutual recursion.

### Functions dealing with mutually recursive types

Consider an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) that keeps position information in every node. The type might look like this:

```ml
type Expr =
  | Int of int
  | Var of string
  | Add of ExprAux * ExprAux
and ExprAux = Expr of int * Expr
```

The easiest way to write functions that manipulate values of these types is to write mutually recursive functions. For example, a function to find the set of free variables:

```ml
let rec freeVariables = function
  | Int n -> Set.empty
  | Var x -> Set.singleton x
  | Add(f, g) -> Set.union (freeVariablesAux f) (freeVariablesAux g)
and freeVariablesAux (Expr(loc, e)) =
  freeVariables e
```

### State machines

Consider a state machine that is either on, off or paused with instructions to start, stop, pause and resume (F# code):

```ml
type Instruction = Start | Stop | Pause | Resume
```

The state machine might be written as mutually recursive functions with one function for each state:

```ml
type State = State of (Instruction -> State)

let rec isOff = function
  | Start -> State isOn
  | _ -> State isOff
and isOn = function
  | Stop -> State isOff
  | Pause -> State isPaused
  | _ -> State isOn
and isPaused = function
  | Stop -> State isOff
  | Resume -> State isOn
  | _ -> State isPaused
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit contrived and not very efficient, but you could do this with a function to calculate Fibbonacci numbers as in:

```
fib2(n) { return fib(n-2); }

fib1(n) { return fib(n-1); }

fib(n)
{
  if (n>1)
    return fib1(n) + fib2(n);
  else
    return 1;
}
```

In this case its efficiency can be dramatically enhanced if the language supports [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoize)

Comment: Mutual Recursion is not the same as Double Recursion, the question describes Mutual Recursion.

Any mutually recursive set of functions can be unrolled into a single recursive function simply by inlining the code.

Comment: You've fixed it now, my comment looks out of place!

Comment: @Geoff: No problem... I got a little carried away and started writing stuff without thinking.

Answer (score 3):

In a language with proper tail calls, Mutual Tail Recursion is a very natural way of implementing automata.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my coded solution.  For a calculator app that performs `*`,`/`,`-` operations using mutual recursion. It also checks for brackets (`()`) to decide the order of precedence.

```
Flow:: expression -> term -> factor -> expression 

    Calculator.h
    #ifndef CALCULATOR_H_
    #define CALCULATOR_H_

    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    /****** A Calculator Class holding expression, term, factor ********/
    class Calculator
    {
    public:
        /**Default Constructor*/
        Calculator();

        /** Parameterized Constructor common for all exception
         * @aparam e exception value
         * */
        Calculator(char e);

        /**
         * Function to start computation
         * @param input - input expression*/
        void start(string input);

        /**
         * Evaluates Term*
         * @param input string for term*/
        double term(string& input);

         /* Evaluates factor*
         * @param input string for factor*/
        double factor(string& input);

         /* Evaluates Expression*
          * @param input string for expression*/
        double expression(string& input);


         /* Evaluates number*
          * @param input string for number*/
        string number(string n);

        /**
         * Prints calculates value of the expression
         * */
        void print();

        /**
         * Converts char to double
         * @param c input char
         * */
        double charTONum(const char* c);

        /**
         * Get error
         */
        char get_value() const;
        /** Reset all values*/
        void reset();
    private:
        int lock;//set lock to check extra parenthesis
        double result;// result
        char error_msg;// error message
    };

    /**Error for unexpected string operation*/
    class Unexpected_error:public Calculator
    {
    public:
        Unexpected_error(char e):Calculator(e){};
    };

    /**Error for missing parenthesis*/
    class Missing_parenthesis:public Calculator
    {
    public:
        Missing_parenthesis(char e):Calculator(e){};
    };

    /**Error if divide by zeros*/
    class DivideByZero:public Calculator{
    public:
        DivideByZero():Calculator(){};
    };
    #endif
    ===============================================================================

    Calculator.cpp

    //============================================================================
    // Name        : Calculator.cpp
    // Author      : Anurag
    // Version     :
    // Copyright   : Your copyright notice
    // Description : Calculator using mutual recursion in C++, Ansi-style
    //============================================================================

    #include "Calculator.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <exception>
    using namespace std;


    Calculator::Calculator():lock(0),result(0),error_msg(' '){

    }

    Calculator::Calculator(char e):result(0), error_msg(e) {

    }

    char Calculator::get_value() const {
        return this->error_msg;
    }

    void Calculator::start(string input) {
        try{
        result = expression(input);
        print();
        }catch (Unexpected_error e) {
            cout<<result<<endl;
            cout<<"***** Unexpected "<<e.get_value()<<endl;
        }catch (Missing_parenthesis e) {
            cout<<"***** Missing "<<e.get_value()<<endl;
        }catch (DivideByZero e) {
            cout<<"***** Division By Zero" << endl;
        }
    }

    double Calculator::expression(string& input) {
        double expression=0;
        if(input.size()==0)
            return 0;
        expression = term(input);
        if(input[0] == ' ')
            input = input.substr(1);
        if(input[0] == '+') {
            input = input.substr(1);
            expression += term(input);
        }
        else if(input[0] == '-') {
            input = input.substr(1);
            expression -= term(input);
        }
        if(input[0] == '%'){
            result = expression;
            throw Unexpected_error(input[0]);
        }
        if(input[0]==')' && lock<=0 )
            throw Missing_parenthesis(')');
        return expression;
    }

    double Calculator::term(string& input) {
        if(input.size()==0)
            return 1;
        double term=1;
        term = factor(input);
        if(input[0] == ' ')
            input = input.substr(1);
        if(input[0] == '*') {
            input = input.substr(1);
            term = term * factor(input);
        }
        else if(input[0] == '/') {
            input = input.substr(1);
            double den = factor(input);
            if(den==0) {
                throw DivideByZero();
            }
            term = term / den;
        }
        return term;
    }

    double Calculator::factor(string& input) {
        double factor=0;
        if(input[0] == ' ') {
            input = input.substr(1);
        }
        if(input[0] == '(') {
            lock++;
            input = input.substr(1);
            factor = expression(input);
            if(input[0]==')') {
                lock--;
                input = input.substr(1);
                return factor;
            }else{
                throw Missing_parenthesis(')');
            }
        }
        else if (input[0]>='0' && input[0]<='9'){
            string nums = input.substr(0,1) + number(input.substr(1));
            input = input.substr(nums.size());
            return stod(nums);
        }
        else {
            result = factor;
            throw Unexpected_error(input[0]);
        }
        return factor;
    }

    string Calculator::number(string input) {
        if(input.substr(0,2)=="E+" || input.substr(0,2)=="E-" || input.substr(0,2)=="e-" || input.substr(0,2)=="e-")
            return input.substr(0,2) + number(input.substr(2));
        else if((input[0]>='0' && input[0]<='9') || (input[0]=='.'))
            return input.substr(0,1) + number(input.substr(1));
        else
            return "";
    }

    void Calculator::print() {
        cout << result << endl;
    }

    void Calculator::reset(){
        this->lock=0;
        this->result=0;
    }
    int main() {

        Calculator* cal = new Calculator;
        string input;
        cout<<"Expression? ";
        getline(cin,input);
        while(input!="."){
            cal->start(input.substr(0,input.size()-2));
            cout<<"Expression? ";
            cal->reset();
            getline(cin,input);
        }
        cout << "Done!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    ==============================================================
    Sample input-> Expression? (42+8)*10 =
    Output-> 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Top down merge sort can use a pair of mutually recursive functions to alternate the direction of merge based on level of recursion.

For the example code below, a[] is the array to be sorted, b[] is a temporary working array. For a naive implementation of merge sort, each merge operation copies data from a[] to b[], then merges b[] back to a[], or it merges from a[] to b[], then copies from b[] back to a[]. This requires n · ceiling(log2(n)) copy operations. To eliminate the copy operations used for merging, the direction of merge can be alternated based on level of recursion, merge from a[] to b[], merge from b[] to a[], ..., and switch to in place insertion sort for small runs in a[], as insertion sort on small runs is faster than merge sort.

In this example, MergeSortAtoA() and MergeSortAtoB() are the mutually recursive functions.

Example java code:

```java
    static final int ISZ = 64;              // use insertion sort if size <= ISZ

    static void MergeSort(int a[])
    {
        int n = a.length;
        if(n < 2)
            return;
        int [] b = new int[n];
        MergeSortAtoA(a, b, 0, n);
    }
    
    static void MergeSortAtoA(int a[], int b[], int ll, int ee)
    {
        if ((ee - ll) <= ISZ){              // use insertion sort on small runs
            InsertionSort(a, ll, ee);
            return;
        }
        int rr = (ll + ee)>>1;              // midpoint, start of right half
        MergeSortAtoB(a, b, ll, rr);
        MergeSortAtoB(a, b, rr, ee);
        Merge(b, a, ll, rr, ee);            // merge b to a
    }
    
    static void MergeSortAtoB(int a[], int b[], int ll, int ee)
    {
        int rr = (ll + ee)>>1;              // midpoint, start of right half
        MergeSortAtoA(a, b, ll, rr);
        MergeSortAtoA(a, b, rr, ee);
        Merge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);            // merge a to b
    }
    
    static void Merge(int a[], int b[], int ll, int rr, int ee)
    {
        int o = ll;                         // b[]       index
        int l = ll;                         // a[] left  index
        int r = rr;                         // a[] right index
    
        while(true){                        // merge data
            if(a[l] <= a[r]){               // if a[l] <= a[r]
                b[o++] = a[l++];            //   copy a[l]
                if(l < rr)                  //   if not end of left run
                    continue;               //     continue (back to while)
                while(r < ee){              //   else copy rest of right run
                    b[o++] = a[r++];
                }
                break;                      //     and return
            } else {                        // else a[l] > a[r]
                b[o++] = a[r++];            //   copy a[r]
                if(r < ee)                  //   if not end of right run
                    continue;               //     continue (back to while)
                while(l < rr){              //   else copy rest of left run
                    b[o++] = a[l++];
                }
                break;                      //     and return
            }
        }
    }

    static void InsertionSort(int a[], int ll, int ee)
    {
        int i, j;
        int t;
        for (j = ll + 1; j < ee; j++) {
            t = a[j];
            i = j-1;
            while(i >= ll && a[i] > t){
                a[i+1] = a[i];
                i--;
            }
            a[i+1] = t;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: I'd be glad to uv, if you'd add some hints as to why the alternation is / could be needed. :)

Comment: I don't read Java freely. is your technique related to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12666/merge-sort-in-scheme) or is it just about the length being something like 2^n+1 ? IOW what is the problem it is solving?

Comment: @WillNess - I updated my answer to include an explanation, and added insertion sort for small runs in the example code.

Comment: ok thanks. but when you merge from b[] to a[], the array b[] is still traversed left-to-right? I thought "direction" mean changing the traversal's direction.

Comment: @WillNess - Yes, the elements needs to be processed left to right for the merge sort to be stable. As for `alternating direction of merge`: one direction would move and merge elements from a[] to b[], and the other direction would move and merge elements from b[] to a[], without any copy step before or after a merge.